# How to Populate Comment Field When Checking in Pending Changes With TFS?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013

Refer to the picture below.  Is there some plugin for Visual Studio, or some OOTB method of pre-populating the comments for the Checkin?  If not, is there was a way to be able to drag the file from the "Included Changes" section into?  I'd even accept a method of spitting out all pending files in some other external program that I could copy paste into the Comments.

[image]

Generally I like to comment my check-ins in this sort of manner:

```
   FileA
   -  MethodA
      - Changed Error Handling
   -  MethodB - Added
   -  MethodC
      - Fix for Bug #8675309

   FileB
   -  MethodFoo - Moved to FileC
```

And it would save <s>a lot of</s> time if I didn't have to type the file check-in hierarchy.

Comment: Why on earth would you need to type out the file hierarchy - the changeset *already* documents that, also it can associate the bugs that are fixed (assuming you integrate them as workitems). I'd advocate keeping changesets like functions - do one thing, and do it well.

Comment: @RowlandShaw is there an easy way to get the changeset documented as text?  Something I could copy.

Comment: Is this an on-premises TFS server? As you *could* (in an unsupported manner) query the database directly

Comment: @RowlandShaw It's on Premise.  But if I haven't checked it in, how does it know what I'm going to checkin?

Comment: I've not got the SQL to hand, but pending changes are in the database

Comment: @RowlandShaw I'll take a look at that route.

Comment: The pending changes are only in the database if you are using Server Workspaces.

Comment: Good point @DaveShaw (guess who doesn't use local workspaces :)

Comment: @RowlandShaw - Ludite :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I alluded to in the comments earlier, I'd advocate trying to keep each check-in for a single work item (be that bug 8675309, or feature X), as the changeset already documents the files that are associated, as well as the associated work items; similarly what has changed (so things like "added method foo") are covered by revision history (or the Annotate feature).

If you use server workspaces, then you can write a report with SQL something like:

```sql
SELECT      u.displayname,
            w.WorkspaceName,
            ISNULL(w.Computer, 'Shelveset'),
            pc.TargetServerItem,
            pc.LockStatus

FROM        [dbo].[tbl_Workspace] w

INNER JOIN  dbo.tbl_PendingChange pc 
    ON      w.WorkspaceId = pc.WorkspaceId

INNER JOIN  [dbo].[tbl_Identity] u 
    ON      w.OwnerId = u.IdentityId
```

Caveat: That SQL was originally for TFS2008, so the schema may have changed. Also worth noting again that Microsoft do not support direct querying like this.

Comment: Do nor run queries against the operational store. Not only is it not supported but it could leave you out of support from the product team. Don't do it. Use the API to get the things that you need...

Answer (score 3):

In your example, I would split that into 4 separate changesets, with the following comments:

1. Changed Error Handling
2. Added MethodB
3. Fixed Bug #123
4. Moved foo to FileC

None of these would be auto-generated, a human needs to type these in.